# Edge Browser input placeholder (text duplicated)

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

[image: screenshot of issue]

This is the html:

```
<input id="testInput" placeholder="something" />
```

*UPDATED*
found this piece of javascript overriding how the "placeholder" attribute works. It seems that it is failing to override it in the Edge browser.

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
(function ($) {
    var default_options = {
        labelClass: 'placeholder'
    };
    var ph = "PLACEHOLDER-INPUT";
    var phl = "PLACEHOLDER-LABEL";
    var boundEvents = false;
    /*
    //using custom placeholder for all browsers now: partials/_formBasics.scss
    //check for browser support for placeholder attribute
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    if('placeholder' in input) {
    $.fn.placeholder = $.fn.unplaceholder = function () { }; //empty function
    delete input;
    return;
    };
    delete input;
    */


    $.fn.placeholder = function (options) {
        bindEvents();
        var opts = $.extend(default_options, options);
        this.each(function () {
            var rnd = Math.random().toString(32).replace(/\./, ''),
            input = $(this),
            label = $('<label style="position:absolute; z-index:100; "></label>');
            if (!input.attr('placeholder') || input.data(ph) === ph) return;
            //make sure the input tag has an ID assigned, if not, assign one.
            if (!input.attr('id')) {
                input.attr('id', 'input_' + rnd);
            }
            label.attr('id', input.attr('id') + "_placeholder").data(ph, '#' + input.attr('id')) //reference to the input tag
        .attr('for', input.attr('id')).addClass(opts.labelClass).addClass(opts.labelClass + '-for-' + this.tagName.toLowerCase()) //ex: watermark-for-textarea
        .addClass(phl).text(input.attr('placeholder'));
            input.data(phl, '#' + label.attr('id')) //set a reference to the label
        .data(ph, ph) //set that the field is watermarked
        .addClass(ph) //add the watermark class
        .before(label); //add the label field to the page
            itemOut.call(this);
        });
        //$('label').disableSelection();
    };
    $.fn.unplaceholder = function () {
        this.each(function () {
            var input = $(this),
            label = $(input.data(phl));
            if (input.data(ph) !== ph) return;
            label.remove();
            input.removeData(ph).removeData(phl).removeClass(ph);
        });
    };

    function bindEvents() {
        if (boundEvents) return;
        $(document).on('click, focusin, change', '.' + ph, itemIn);
        $(document).on('focusout', '.' + ph, itemOut);
        $(document).on('keyup', '.' + ph, itemKeyStroke);
        bound = true;
        boundEvents = true;
    };

    function itemIn() {
        var input = $(this),
    label = $(input.data(phl));
        if ($(input).val().length > 0)
            $(label).addClass('hasValue').removeClass('FocusNoValue');
        else
            $(label).addClass('FocusNoValue').removeClass('hasValue');
    };

    function itemOut() {
        var input = $(this),
    label = $(input.data(phl));            
        if ($(input).val().length > 0)
            $(label).addClass('hasValue').removeClass('FocusNoValue');
        else
            $(label).removeClass('FocusNoValue').removeClass('hasValue');
    };
    function itemKeyStroke() {
        var input = $(this),
        label = $(input.data(phl));
        if ($(input).val().length > 0)
            $(label).addClass('hasValue').removeClass('FocusNoValue');
        else
            $(label).addClass('FocusNoValue').removeClass('hasValue');
    };
} (jQuery)); //placeholder
```

});

Comment: You need to be way more specific! this fiddle looks fine in IE Edge https://jsfiddle.net/88z7u4kf/3/

Comment: I just found a piece of javascript that is overriding the "placeholder" attribute. So I'm getting closer. I'll update this question with that.

Comment: Yeah, javascript sounds like it could be a possible cause.

Comment: Thanks, Now give us a working fiddle if possible.

Comment: What if you remove the placeholder content in the input tag? It seems that the query is adding another one in there.

Comment: Thanks for the interest everyone. The above commented code "check for browser support..." - not sure why it was commented out. Putting that code back in has fixed the issue.

Comment: wondering if I should delete this. Not sure if it's going to help anyone in the future.

Comment: I think if you were to answer your same question IT WOULD BE USEFUL, I check in a lot of places and found a similar problem with no solutions. Create an easy to understand answer and I will up vote it.

Comment: Putting the "check for browser support" code back in isn't necessary and might be against the design of the app. The comment says that the app is "using [a] custom placeholder for all browsers now: partials/_formBasics.scss" That means that checking for browser support is no longer necessary, because there is some new CSS that enables the custom placeholder for all browsers. That CSS is within a [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not just in Edge that the jQuery custom placeholder was not working. It was also looking poor in Firefox. That's because the plugin needs CSS too. The comment about browser support says that the relevant CSS is in this SASS file: `partials/_formBasics.scss`. I recommended tweaking that [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) in order to support the new Edge browser.

As an example, [this fiddle fixes it in both Edge and Firefox by adding some CSS.](http://jsfiddle.net/shaunluttin/z3h2evyg/) These are the CSS classes that the plugin uses:

- `placeholder`
- `placeholder-for-input`
- `PLACEHOLDER-LABEL`
- `hasValue`
- `FocusNoValue`

You do not need to use them all. The fiddle added only the following. We hide the placeholder, align the label, and hide the label when appropriate.

```
label.placeholder {
    color:red;
    font-family:arial;
    /* hide the placeholder */
    background-color:white; 
    /* align the label */
    margin-top:0.1rem;
    margin-left:0.1rem;
    font-size:0.9rem;
}
label.hasValue, label.FocusNoValue {
    /* hide the label when appropriate */
    display:none !important;
}
```

## Fixed result in Edge

[image: Red custom placeholder in Edge]

Comment: This CSS is included in the _formBasics.scss file:

label.placeholder {
 cursor: text;
 font-weight:normal !important;
 padding: 4px 4px 4px 5px;
 color: #999999;
 display:block;
}
label.hasValue{display:none !important;}
label.FocusNoValue{color:#ccc;}

Comment: Yo @Induster Good to know. Do you want me to add something about that to my answer?

Comment: I'm testing to see if it corrects the issue by adding display:none !important to the label.FocusNoValue